# cannot allocate memory error

Tags: go, ubuntu-14.04

I just ported my app over from python so I'm a bit new to Go.  It seems I am having a memory issues.  `getAudioOnlyInfo: fork/exec /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl: cannot allocate memory.`

This is run on a ubuntu machine.  Via supervisor.

Edit:

setting the `sysctl -w vm.swappiness=1` resolve the issue

Comment: You probably have a memory leak, but it's hard to tell from that one function. If you want to fight symptoms, maybe add swap to your machine. Also analyze your code for potential memory leaks. What hardware are you running on?

Comment: @Riscie the swapiness is good enough for the swap no.  What else would be needed to find the memory leak?

Comment: The go blog has an article about profiling apps which could help you http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

Comment: Are you using some libraries which are Go to C bindings? If yes, check that you have freed all resources you've allocated using those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this problem, it was a related recent issue [in the golang issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5838#issuecomment-171280473)

> For all those affected, temporary workaround on Linux until it is
>   fixed properly can be one of following:
>
> 1. enable unconditional overcommit: `sysctl -w vm.overcommit_memory=1`
> 2. enable unconditional overcommit: `sysctl -w vm.overcommit_memory=1` add swap to your host, with `sysctl -w vm.swappiness=1` it will almost
>      never going to be used, but it participates in calculations where
>      Linux kernel decides to whether it can afford to satisfy allocation or
>      not when `default overcommit_memory=0` is in use