# How can I get linux to reduce its VIRT memory allocation for a golang process?

Tags: linux, go, out-of-memory

from: https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#MemStats

> Alloc uint64 // bytes allocated and not yet freed
>   Sys   uint64 // bytes obtained from system

In my long running go program I'm printing out:

```
var mem runtime.MemStats
runtime.ReadMemStats(&mem)
fmt.Println("%d, %d", mem.Alloc/1048576, mem.Sys/1048576)
```

And I see values like:

```
200, 800
350, 910
198, 910
```

i.e. the first number mem.Alloc goes up and down. The 2nd number mem.Sys only goes up never down.

When I look at top -p pid for the process I see the Resident memory is always in between the two numbers. Another way to say that, top always says the memory is a little more than what mem.Alloc reports but way less than mem.Sys. Sometimes the Sys number gets rather large:

800, 4590

and my program is in a bad state. 4.5 gigs of used memroy? But top and Alloc say it's only using about 1 gig. The bad state is I can't run:

```
  cmd := exec.Command(path, args...)
  cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
  cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
  cmd.ExtraFiles = []*os.File{file}
  err := cmd.Start()
```

because I get the error "fork/exec /path/to/exec: cannot allocate memory"

How can I get that mem.Sys number to go down and be able to run cmd := exec.Command, and then cmd.Start()?

Update: see [How can I get linux to reduce its VIRT memory allocation for a golang process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816250/how-can-i-get-golang-sys-memory-value-to-drop#comment66923941_39816250)

Comment: Sys is the total amount allocated. It's a counter, it never goes down.

Comment: i see. But there is some correlation between when that number is very large and when I get that cannot create process error. So at some point my program takes enough memory to trigger that state. And even though it gives it back, I still can't fork.

Comment: What is the system memory state when the program fails? What is the exact error message?

Comment: exact error message is "fork/exec /path/to/exec: cannot allocate memory". And system memory state is fine, the box has 12 gigs and very little is in use.

Comment: ah, "@bioothod when fork fails, it's because it cannot allocate enough virtual memory to (potentially) hold a copy of the daemon's allocated virtual memory, so the resident set size of 1.1 GB is irrelevant. Your daemon using 30.4 GB of virtual memory when the problem manifests makes your report consistent with others, as far as I can tell. Which does not tell us where this virtual memory leak comes from, though." from https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8539#issuecomment-244318346

Comment: sure enough my pid's VIRT is 5406364 or 5.4 gigs and 2x that would not fit.

Comment: this is good info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35027241/148736